# BeanIO - How to detect multiple record with same type

Tags: java, annotations, reader, bean-io

How to detect, in a fixed length file, the same record type?
BeanIO dected only first record header without the others two documents.
What I would like is to obtain wrapper class with the three documents and their item codes.

This is an example of fixed length txt file:

```
Unknown record
Unknown record
RH20210607A
RDitem1
RDitem2
Unknown record
RH20210607B
RDitem2
RDitem3
Unknown record
Unknown record
Unknown record
RH20210607C
RDitem1
RDitem4
RDitem5
```

I want to detect the header (RH) and detail (RD) record.

I designed a group list with another group for each subgroup.

Top group class:

```
@Group(name = "fixedFile")
public class ListDocumentWrapper {

    @Group(minOccurs=1, type=Document.class, collection = List.class)
    List<Document> documentList;
}
```

Subgroup class:

```
@Data
public class Document{

    @Record(order = 1, minOccurs=1, maxOccurs=1)
    private RH recordHeader;
    @Record(order = 2, minOccurs=1, type=RD.class, collection = List.class)
    private List<RD> recordDetails;
}
```

Single record class:

```
@Data
@Record
public class RH{

    @Field(ordinal = 0, required = true, length = 2, align = Align.LEFT, rid = true, literal = "RH")
    private String recordType;

    @Field(ordinal = 1, required = true, length=8, format = "yyyyMMdd")
    private LocalDate documentDate;

    @Field(ordinal = 2, required = true, length = 1, padding = ' ', align = Align.LEFT)
    private String documentCode;
}
```

```
@Data
@Record
public class RD{

    @Field(ordinal = 0, required = true, length = 2, align = Align.LEFT, rid = true, literal = "RD")
    private String recordType;

    @Field(ordinal = 1, required = true, length = 5, padding = ' ', align = Align.LEFT)
    private String itemCode;
}
```

Init of BeanReader:

```
// create a StreamFactory
StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
// load the mapping file
String streamBuilderName = "fixedFile";
        factory.define(
                new StreamBuilder(streamBuilderName)
                        .format("fixedlength")
                        .parser(new FixedLengthParserBuilder())
                        .ignoreUnidentifiedRecords()
                        .addGroup(ListDocumentWrapper.class)
        );

BeanReader beanReader = factory.createReader(streamBuilderName, aFileReader, Locale.ITALIAN);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please also show how you constructed and initialized your `BeanReader` instance

Comment: I updated the initialization part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the right solution, but I found a workaround.

***The desire is to make a single read and get a list of document***

This is the workaround.

First I didn't understand that **beanReader.read()** extract the first element of stream. So it's no necessary to create **ListDocumentWrapper** but read all **Document** with a simple **while loop**.

This is the extract of code:

```
List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
Document documentMessage = null;
int documentIndex = 0;
        while ((documentMessage = (Document) beanReader.read()) != null) {
            // process the documentMessage...
            log.debug("Reading documentMessage ["+documentIndex+"]... => " + documentMessage);

            documentList.add(documentMessage);
            documentIndex++;
        }
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution